# (Swift HomeKit) App takes two refreshes of the view controller to reflect accessory value change

Tags: ios, swift, homekit

I'm writing an app to control home kit accessories (lightbulbs), except in my view controller, when I update say the Boolean on/off status of a characteristic, it takes me two iterations of going back and forth between the view controller for it to reflect the changed values.

Could this be a problem with the delegate? I don't know what to do with this.

I have an accessory view UISwitch for each table cell that controls the power state of a lightbulb, and I have a UISwitch at the toolbar at the top that is supposed to turn all of the lights on or off.

here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method, where powercharacteristic is an array of the power Status characteristics of all the lightbulbs,

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cellIdentifier = "DeviceTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! DeviceTableViewCell
    cell.deviceName.text = devices[indexPath.row].name



    //creating the switch
    let deviceSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRect.zero) as UISwitch

    //init the switch
    updateValues()
    let isOn = powerCharacteristic[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].value as! Bool
    deviceSwitch.setOn(isOn, animated: true)

    //letting switch know what cell called it
    deviceSwitch.tag = (indexPath as NSIndexPath).row

    //adding selector
    deviceSwitch.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeStatusFromButton), for: .valueChanged)

    //adding cell in table
    cell.accessoryView = deviceSwitch

    //on Off Label
    if isOn {
        cell.isOnOrOff.text = "On"
    } else {
        cell.isOnOrOff.text = "Off"
    }


    return cell
}
```

and this part works. But when I flip the switch at the top,

```
@IBAction func mainSwitchToggled(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    writeAllValue()

}
```

which calls

```
func writeAllValue() {
    for characteristic in powerCharacteristic{

        characteristic.writeValue(mainSwitch.isOn, completionHandler: {(error) in
            if error != nil {
                print("Something went wrong with writing all value")
            } else {
                print("Writing all Value Successful")
            }})

    }
    tableView.reloadData()



}
```

It gets off cycle, and ends up turning them !on or !off depending on the state of the switch.

Comment: Please provide some code.

Comment: I did, and the problem is also that If I change the value of an accessory in the home kit simulator, it again takes me two times of going back and forth between view controllers in my app for the changes to be reflected on the buttons on the table view cell